# What is use of toolbar and action bar?

Tags: android

I am new to android i didn't understand what is the use of toolbar. In place of toolbar we can use any layout like relativelayout then we can design it. 
And in  toolbar if you want add any button we are creating menu folder and we are doing so many nonsense thing
So inplace of taking toolbar better to take layout. 
Please anyone give me the answer why we are using toolbar and actionbar

Answer (score 1):

Toolbars are useful because you can use them in layouts, apply any themes and even create a menu. Toolbars extend [viewgroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar) - that's makes them extra flexible. They are used in layouts to create material designed themed apps. Why does that matter? That's what the users on Android are used to and if you have a custom toolbar you might confuse your potential users. And you get all of this functionality for free, instead of using a layout and manually setting the styles and menus.

So why should you use the supplied toolbar? It's the same with using any component created for use on Android; Don't Repeat Yourself. DRY is the golden rule of software development, and by using these layouts across apps it makes it easier for the users of your apps to understand how to use your apps

Answer (score 0):

It's not an absolute requirement to have a Toolbar, but it has been a staple of the material design paradigm for a while. On many apps, it's used to show the app title, or to house navigation components for example. I suggest you take some time and read the material design rationale for the Toolbar. https://material.io/develop/web/components/toolbar/

The documentation provides some context and suggested usages of the ToolBar in the first sentence of the description.

> MDC (Material Design Component) Toolbar acts as a container for multiple rows containing items such as application title, navigation menu, and tabs, among other things.